# How to get the scroll amount if a div has the scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

So the page doesn't have scroll property. A div has elements inside it with the scroll property.
I m looking for a `pageYOffset` equivalent for a div to know its scrolled length.

```js
const childern = document.querySelectorAll(".childern");
const parent = document.querySelector(".container");

parent.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  console.log(pageYOffset); //I need to change this
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}
.childern {
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
.one {
  background-color: black;
}
.two {
  background-color: rgb(36, 36, 36);
}
.three {
  background-color: rgb(71, 71, 71);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="childern one"></div>
      <div class="childern two"></div>
      <div class="childern three"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parent.scrollTop` is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `scrollHeight` if you want to know the elements scroll length.  If you mean to see how far an element has been scrolled, you can use `scrollTop`.

Like this:

```js
const scrollable = document.querySelector('.scrollable')

// This should print 500, which is the same height as the child div
// "content".
console.log(scrollable.scrollHeight)

scrollable.addEventListener("scroll", e => {
  // This shows how far down in the element we've scrolled.
  console.log(scrollable.scrollTop)
})
```

```css
.scrollable {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollable">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works,check this out.

```js
const childern = document.querySelectorAll(".childern");
const parent = document.querySelector(".container");

parent.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  console.log(parent.scrollTop); //I need to change this
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}
.childern {
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
.one {
  background-color: black;
}
.two {
  background-color: rgb(36, 36, 36);
}
.three {
  background-color: rgb(71, 71, 71);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="childern one"></div>
      <div class="childern two"></div>
      <div class="childern three"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```